# Search strings in dataframe column for specific pattern and update with another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Let's say I have the following sample dataframe:

```
# Create DataFrame from Dict
technologies = {
    'Val':[5, 9],
    'Stuff':["[demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]", "<text-ali>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]"]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
```

How can I quickly replace the integers within the square brackets of the "Stuff" column with "Val"?

For example, my desired output will be:

```
technologies = {
    'Val':[5, 9],
    'Stuff':["[demography_form][5]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][5]", "<text-ali>[geography_form][9]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][9]"]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
```

The number of each "[int]" may change in subsequent rows and the position is not consistent. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any better solution than [applying](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)  like in the following snippet

```py
import re

df.apply(
    lambda x: re.sub(
        r"\[\d\]", # pattern to replace, in this example, 
                 # a single digit enclosed in square brackets
        f"[{x['Val']}]", # string to use as a replacement
        x['Stuff'] # where 
    ), axis=1) # axis along which apply will be appplied :)
```

Comment: any idea why this is replacing values not enclosed in brackets as well?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape brackets. I am going to edit it